# How to change the two-dimensional array into a one-dimensional array by my case below?

Tags: php, arrays

My array is like this :

```
$data = array( 
                    10 => array(
                                "id"    => 50, 
                                "name"  => 'chelsea'
                        ),
                    11 => array(
                                "id"    => 51, 
                                "name"  => 'real madrid'
                        )
            );
```

I want change the array to be like this :

```
Array
(
    [10] => 50
    [11] => 51
)
```

I try like this :

```
$data = array_column($data, 'id');
```

But, the result like this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 50
    [1] => 51
)
```

If there exist people who can solve my problem?

Comment: `$data = array_combine(array_keys($data), array_column($data, 'id'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = array( 
    10 => array(
        "id"    => 50, 
        "name"  => 'chelsea'
    ),
    11 => array(
        "id"    => 51, 
        "name"  => 'real madrid'
    )
);

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $new_data[$key] = $value['id'];
}

var_dump($new_data);
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

**You have to declare and load a new array with the new information like so**

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
   $new_array[$key] = $value['id'];
}
print_r($new_array); //display newly loaded data
```